# How can I select these elements and wrap them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a title followed by two radio inputs and I need to wrap them so I can style them in a form

```
<p><strong>Country</strong></p>
<div class="radioWrapper">
     <span class="label">Canada</span>
     <span class="radio">
          <input type="radio" value="Canada">
     </span>
</div>
<div class="radioWrapper">
     <span class="label">US</span>
     <span class="radio">
          <input type="radio" value="US">
     </span>
</div>
```

That's what I have, and around the whole thing I'd like a containing div. I tried to write some jquery, but it didn't work -

```
$( "strong:contains('Country')" ).nextAll( "div.radioWrapper" ).wrapAll("<div class='RadioWrap'></div>");
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction

Comment: You don't need to wrap them in a div to style them... Elaborate on what you need to be selected, and we can help you come up with a css-only selector

Comment: Actually I do need to wrap it, I want to float it with the surrounding divs so it fits in my design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct. Just select parent `p` element and from there search for next `.radioWrapper`. Note, that you also have to include `p` with `andSelf` method:

```
$( "strong:contains('Country')")
    .closest('p')
    .nextAll("div.radioWrapper").andSelf()
    .wrapAll("<div class='RadioWrap'></div>");
```

Or another version using nextUnti method:

```
$("strong:contains('Country')")
    .closest('p')
    .nextUntil(":not(.radioWrapper)").andSelf()
    .wrapAll("<div class='RadioWrap'></div>");
```

Check the demo below.

```js
$( "strong:contains('Country')").closest('p').nextAll( "div.radioWrapper" ).andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='RadioWrap'></div>");
```

```css
.RadioWrap {background: #EEE;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Country</strong></p>
<div class="radioWrapper">
     <span class="label">Canada</span>
     <span class="radio">
          <input type="radio" value="Canada">
     </span>
</div>
<div class="radioWrapper">
     <span class="label">US</span>
     <span class="radio">
          <input type="radio" value="US">
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you! it's slightly working, It does wrap the correct tags together but it also brings in all of the other radioWrappers on the page, is there a way I can limit it to just two?

Answer (score 1):

The `p` is the sibling of the divs so that is what you have to select first not the `b`, try

```
$( "p:has(strong:contains('Country'))" ).nextAll( "div.radioWrapper:lt(2)" ).wrapAll("<div class='RadioWrap'></div>")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ya3arznn/1/

---

```js
$( "p:has(strong:contains('Country'))" ).nextAll( "div.radioWrapper:lt(2)" ).wrapAll("<div class='RadioWrap'></div>")
```

```css
.RadioWrap {color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Country</strong></p>
<div class="radioWrapper">
     <span class="label">Canada</span>
     <span class="radio">
          <input type="radio" value="Canada">
     </span>
</div>
<div class="radioWrapper">
     <span class="label">Trinidad</span>
     <span class="radio">
          <input type="radio" value="Trinidad">
     </span>
</div>
<div class="radioWrapper">
     <span class="label">US</span>
     <span class="radio">
          <input type="radio" value="US">
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you! it's slightly working, same as the solution about - It does wrap the correct tags together but it also brings in all of the other radioWrappers on the page, is there a way I can limit it to just two?

Comment: You can use the `lt` filter `:lt(2)` on the div

Answer (score 1):

to limit to two with minimal code, I'd do this:

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/990f342d52121621d07306e7a5fd8f63)

```
  $( "p:contains('Country')" )
    .add( ".radioWrapper:lt(2)" )
    .wrapAll("<div class='RadioWrap'/>");
```

[image: wrapper]